# Close Button in cases

Tags: apex, custom-button, administration, case

I want to have a close button in case layout in community but do not want to give him a permission of edit, create  or delete. just close case. how can we do that.

Comment: To close the case you have to update the case. How would you do that without edit permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow users to edit records they normally wouldn't be able to by using an `Apex Class` that has `without sharing` declared. A very simple example:

**Markup**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CloseCaseExtension" action="{!closeCase}">
    <apex:pageMessages />
</apex:page>
```

**Code**

```
public without sharing class CloseCaseExtension
{
    final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public CloseCaseExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public PageReference closeCase()
    {
        record = (Case)controller.getRecord();
        record.Status = 'Closed';
        try
        {
            update record;
        }
        catch (DmlException dmx)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(dmx);
            return null;
        }
        return controller.view();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code example is with sharing...